# Angular Editable Material Table

Tags: angular, user-interface

I am using Material tables and having a hard time finding an example of editable Material table. I found one example but I have no idea how would that fit with my existing code..he is the best link I found
Link:https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular4-material-table

plunker:https://plnkr.co/edit/9kZfUW?p=preview

here is my code also I am open for any suggestion if someone uses other kind of editable tables. Also before I tried to add the editable feature my table was displaying & working properly with sorting and search. Now I need to make it editable

HTML

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="ID">
                            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID </mat-header-cell>
                            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                                {{row.ID}}

                            </mat-cell>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="Comment">
                            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Commment </mat-header-cell>
                            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">

                                <mat-form-field floatPlaceholder="{{ row.editing ? 'float' : 'never'}}">
                                    <input [formControl]="row.validator.controls['Comment']" [readonly]="!row.editing" placeholder="Comment" [(ngModel)]="row.currentData.Comment" matInput>
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </mat-cell>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="actionsColumn">
                            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                                <button mat-icon-button color="accent" (click)="dataSource.createNew()"><i class="fa fa-plus mat-icon"></i></button>
                            </mat-header-cell>
                            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                                <button *ngIf="!row.editing" mat-icon-button color="primary" focusable="false" (click)="row.startEdit()">
                                    <i class="fa fa-pencil mat-icon"></i>
                                </button>
                                <button *ngIf="row.editing" mat-icon-button color="primary" focusable="false" (click)="row.confirmEditCreate()">
                                    <i class="fa fa-check mat-icon"></i>
                                </button>
                                <button mat-icon-button color="primary" focusable="false" (click)="row.cancelOrDelete()">
                                    <i class="fa fa-times mat-icon"></i>
                                </button>
                            </mat-cell>
                        </ng-container>
                        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
                        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns:displayedColumns"></mat-row>
                    </mat-table>
                    <mat-paginator #paginator
                                   [pageSize]="10"
                                   [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]">
                    </mat-paginator>
```

Interface

```
export interface IToDoList {

    ID: number,
    Comment: string
}
```

component.ts

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    toDoList: IToDoList[] = null;
    dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
    @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
    displayedColumns = ['Comment'];

     ngOnInit(): void { 
        this.GetToDoList(this.userID);
    }
    onOpen() {

        this._dashboardService.delBSAFollowup(this.selectedRowID).subscribe(() => {
          //  this.showMessage('File has been uploaded successfully!', 'alert alert-success');
           this.getBSAFollowup();

        },
          error => console.log('Upload File: '));

    }

    GetToDoList(ID: string) {
        this._dashboardService.getToDoList(ID)
            .subscribe(
            data => {
              //  this.toDoList = data.result;
                //this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data.result);
                this.dataSource.data = data.result;
                  },
            error => console.log('GetControls Method: ' + <any>error, 'alert alert-danger'));
    }

     ngAfterViewInit() {

        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }
    applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
        filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
        filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
        this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
    }

}
```

service.ts

```
import { IToDoList } from './toDoList';
@Injectable()

export class DashboardService {


    baseAPIURL: string;
    constructor(private _http: Http) {



    }

    getToDoList(psnlUID:string) {


        return this._http.get(environment.BASE_API_URL + 'XXXXX/' + ID)
            .map((response: Response) => response.json())
            .do(data => console.log('All' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);

    }


    private handleError(error: Response) {
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server Error');
    }
}
```

****************************************************Update**************************************************

```
HTML
               <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="ID">
                            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID </mat-header-cell>
                            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">

    {{row.currentData.id}}


                            </mat-cell>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="Comment">
                            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Commment </mat-header-cell>
                            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                                <mat-form-field floatPlaceholder="{{ row.editing ? 'float' : 'never'}}">
                                    <input matInput [formControl]="row.validator.controls['Comment']" placeholder="Comment" [(ngModel)]="row.currentData.Comment">
                                </mat-form-field>
                                                 </mat-cell>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="actionsColumn">
                            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                                <button mat-icon-button color="accent" (click)="dataSource.createNew()"><i class="fa fa-plus mat-icon"></i></button>
                            </mat-header-cell>
                            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                                <button *ngIf="!row.editing" mat-icon-button color="primary" focusable="false" (click)="row.startEdit()">
                                    <i class="fa fa-pencil mat-icon"></i>
                                </button>
                                <button *ngIf="row.editing" mat-icon-button color="primary" focusable="false" (click)="row.confirmEditCreate()">
                                    <i class="fa fa-check mat-icon"></i>
                                </button>
                                <button mat-icon-button color="primary" focusable="false" (click)="row.cancelOrDelete()">
                                    <i class="fa fa-times mat-icon"></i>
                                </button>
                            </mat-cell>
                        </ng-container>
                        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
                        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns:displayedColumns"></mat-row>
                    </mat-table>
                    <mat-paginator #paginator
                                   [pageSize]="10"
                                   [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]">
                    </mat-paginator>
```

TodoItemValidatorService.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class TodoItemValidatorService implements ValidatorService {
    getRowValidator(): FormGroup {
        return new FormGroup({

            'Comment': new FormControl(),
        });
    }
}
```

component.ts

```
    class TodoItem {
        ID: number;
        Comment: string;
    }
    export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
     @Output() personListChange = new EventEmitter<TodoItem>();
    dataSource: TableDataSource<TodoItem>;
    @Output() personListChange = new EventEmitter<TodoItem>();

        @Input() todoList = [];

        constructor(private _dashboardService:  private todoItemValidator: ValidatorService) {

            _appParams.AdminPSNLUID.subscribe((val) => {
                this.userID = val;
            });

        }

      ngOnInit(): void {

            this.GetToDoList(this.userID);
            this.dataSource = new TableDataSource<any>(this.todoList, TodoItem, this.todoItemValidator);

    this.dataSource.datasourceSubject.subscribe(todoList => this.personListChange.emit(todoList));


        }

    GetToDoList(ID: string) {
            this._dashboardService.getToDoList(ID)
                .subscribe(
                data => {

                     this.dataSource.updateDatasource(data.result);
                      },
                error => console.log('GetControls Method: ' + <any>error, 'alert alert-danger'));
        }


    }
```

service

```
@Injectable()

export class DashboardService {


    baseAPIURL: string;
    constructor(private _http: Http) {



    }

    getToDoList(psnlUID:string) {


        return this._http.get(environment.BASE_API_URL + 'XXXXX/' + ID)
            .map((response: Response) => response.json())
            .do(data => console.log('All' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);

    }


    private handleError(error: Response) {
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server Error');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your plunker seems to work

Comment: yes but it is not working with my code..I have more complex code since I have a service to load the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow these steps:

1. Create a class with the data you want to store. I'd suggest you to use `lowerCamelCase` for variables:

   ```
   public class Comment {
     id: number;
     comment: string;
   }
   ```
2. Instantiate a new `TableDataSource` with the class you specified. In the example you've specified, you're instatianting `MatTableDataSource`:

   ```
   this.dataSource = new TableDataSource<any>([], Comment);
   // The array is empty, if you want to have initial elements just pass a filled array.
   ```
3. If you followed the advice to use `lowerCamelCasing`, then remember to
   change your `html` file.

Next time you have issues with the specific package, you can open an issue directly in the [package's repo](https://github.com/irossimoline/angular4-material-table) and I'll gladly answer there.

---

Edit:

I'd suggest you to read the [angular4-material-table](https://github.com/irossimoline/angular4-material-table)'s repo `readme.md` where you can find the available methods and properties for row (`TableElement`) and `TableDataSource`. If that info is not enough, i,'ll encourage you to [navigate into the code](https://github.com/irossimoline/angular4-material-table/blob/master/src/table-data-source.ts) and see method descriptions.

Comment: I am still not sure what do you mean...my issue is trying to implement row.startEdit(), row.confirmEditCreate() for the comment field see above code..I dot' want the edit to be in a popup box but rather a text box is enabled for the comment to be edited within the grid..Can you help? i can't find documentation for it

Comment: Isee what you mean about creating a class to store my data, i still don't know how to connect the pieces together ..how can I do that with  my above code..how can I call this new class

Comment: I see that you are using:
 `dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();` 

instead of:

`dataSource = new TableDataSource<any>([], Comment);`.

That's probably the problem in your code.

Comment: I am bit confused on how to fit this in my code... I already have an interface and service class.. can you show me how will that work with my code? I updated my above code to show the interface and service class

Comment: Please check this [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/3Qr8mRz4tp5FeK0k7z0u?p=preview). It does not follow the comments I made about good code practices because I've copy/pasted the most I could from your code to show you how it works.

Comment: i am getting two errors..see above code under "Updated". 1)Data does not exist on type " 'TableDataSource<TodoItem>' when using   this.dataSource.data = data.result;   and 'Then' is not a property under   this.dataSource.datasourceSubject.subscribe.then....Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Hi I have one error " this.dataSource.datasourceSubject.then is not a function" also changed  this.dataSource = data.result;

Comment: got ride of the error ...updated my code..now getting one error "Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined  --coming from the HTML Page"

Comment: Check you are using the correct `id` on `controls[id]` in HTML code. The ID's must match the `FormControl`s inside the `FormGroup` created by the service. In your original post were 'ID' and 'Comment'.

Comment: I confirmed I am using ID and Comment..I think the issue is , I am not binding the table correctly --see function GetToDoList from component.ts..also confirmed service is returning ID and Comment..updated my above code

Comment: an update ..        if I comment out from html  <mat-form-field floatPlaceholder="{{ row.editing ? 'float' : 'never'}}">
                                    <input matInput [formControl]="row.validator.controls['Comment']" placeholder="Comment" [(ngModel)]="row.currentData.Comment">
                                </mat-form-field>
the table binds correctly...therefore..I am using ID and Comment correctly

Comment: In `GetToDoList(ID)` method, you are assigning datasource to a JSON. If you want to update the datasource with a new list, you should use `updateDatasource(...)` instead. In your case it could be `datasource.updateDatasource(data.result)`. Please check the repo for more information about datasource and it's use.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help..can you direct me to the documentation ? When I go to https://material.angular.io/cdk/table/overview I only see the cdk stuff..I was able to implement the grid full if it not using TableDateSource (display,paging and sort) however, I can't see anything about TableDataSource? so I can read about how to use DataSource. ID should not be editable only the comment. So I updated my above code (took out the id in the validator class)..now {{row.ID}} is not displaying the id...If you can share the link for the documentation for TableDateSource will be great

Comment: I got it working , never-mind...it will e great if you can share the docs for TableDataSource so I can ready about DataSource